# Using build with belongs_to that uses :class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi guys I'm having issues using `build`

```
Bag
 belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
 has_many :users, :through => :assignments

User
 has_many :bags, :through => :assignments

Assignment
 attr_accessible :bag_id, :user_id
 belongs_to :bag
 belongs_to :user
```

I'm just trying to create a `Bag` that properly uses `current_user's id` to set the foreign key. But what keeps happening is that

Rails properly creates `Bag` but instead of setting Bag.creator_id to current_user.id it `inserts` an entry to `Assignments` using both `bag's id` and `current_user's id`. Could someone please help me out? I'm at wits end.

```
current_user.bags.build type: "Prada", price: 50
current_user.save
```

Comment: I'm assume you have a form...  Put that code here also.  controller create action would be good also

Comment: No I was trying it out using rails c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `User` only knows of bags through `assignments` which is why it's using it.  What you really need is a `creator` equivalent for bags if you want to skip the rel table like:

```
User
 has_many :bags, :through => :assignments
 has_many :creations, :class_name => 'Bag'

bag = current_user.creations.build type: "Prada", price: 50
bag.save
```

Comment: Seems logical but that solution gives me Bag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "bags".* FROM "bags" WHERE "bags"."user_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column bags.user_id does not exist. Ideas?

Comment: Okay figured it out, I had to add a :foreign_key option to has_many :) would you please add that to your answer so that I can select your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I think your models should be like this

```
Bag
 belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
 has_many :assignments
 has_many :users, :through => :assignments

User
 has_many :assignments
 has_many :bags, :through => :assignments

Assignment
 belongs_to :bag
 belongs_to :user
 attr_accessible :bag_id, :user_id
```

Try

```
bag = current_user.bags.build type: "Prada", price: 50
bag.save
```

or

```
current_user.bags.create type: "Prada", price: 50
```

Comment: Yup that's how it looks like I just didn't paste all of it.